# Nodejs uncaughtException event not fired if exception occurred inside express handler

Tags: node.js

I have caught `uncaughtException` event in my nodejs app to write a log when an exception occurred.

```
process.on('uncaughtException', (err) => {
    log.warn('Caught exception. Exiting. error: ' + err + ', stack: ' + err.stack);
    process.exit(1);
});
```

But, above handler is not called when an exception is thrown inside an express event handler.

```
someInvalidFunc();    //This causes the uncaughtException handler to get called.

app.all('/ping', function (req, res, next) {
    someInvalidFunc();  //This doesn't cause the uncaughtException handler to get called.
    res.status(200).json({status: 'OK'});
});
```

Even though the handler is not called, the error is printed to console.

> Error: ReferenceError: someInvalidFunc is not defined

What is the reason for this? How can I catch all unhandled exceptions in the app?

Comment: What happens if you move `someInvalidFunc();` below the app.call?

Comment: @SanSolo It doesn't make any difference. (It causes the `uncaughtException` handler to run)

Comment: Oh ok. I wanted to see if the first call is actually considered a definition

Answer (score 2):

If you are using express, the uncaughtException callback won't be even triggered as express provides a default error handler that catches error from the controller and sends 500 as a response.

You can override the error handler. 
This is explained in the docs:
https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, user has already override using uncaughtException, https://nodejs.org/api/process.html#process_event_uncaughtexception

Comment: What I mean is that express can catch the exception and send a 500 error. The uncaughtException callback wouldn't even be triggered. You can see what I mean here: https://expressjs.com/en/guide/error-handling.html in the default error handler section

Comment: @YogeshDevgun it doesn't matter since this exception is **caught** (by Express) so it's no longer uncaught and therefore doesn't invoke the `uncaughtException` handler either.